# jquery array of background positions with set links

Tags: jquery, arrays, background, position

Okay I've been working on this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sionts/2gMHv/16/). Basically it is four buttons which control the background image position but going from position to position is isn't smooth. Would there be a better way of doing the samething?

Here is my Code:

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <ul>
            <li id="btn-0">button-1</li>
            <li id="btn-1">button-2</li>
            <li id="btn-2">button-3</li>
            <li id="btn-3">button-4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').click(function () {
        currClick = $(this).index();
        bgPos = [{
            'background-position-x': '0px',
                'background-position-y': '0px'
        }, // 0
        {
            'background-position-x': '-50px',
                'background-position-y': '-150px'
        }, // 1
        {
            'background-position-x': '150px',
                'background-position-y': '-20px'
        }, // 2
        {
            'background-position-x': '-200px',
                'background-position-y': '-250px'
        } // 3
        ];
        $('#container').animate(bgPos[currClick], 1500, 'swing');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    background-image:url("http://postmediawindsorstar.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/cat_shot_by_arrow-1.jpg");
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-250px;
    left:50%;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
}
li {
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Also if you spam click the buttons, it does not stop its current animation before moving to the next position.

Comment: `$('#container').stop().animate ...` will fix the spamming problem. It's quite smooth on my pc, if you want it to perform better you have to use CSS transitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Animations are much quicker than js in the browser.  I would look into them:

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/

Comment: Ill look into css transitions first and see how I go

Answer (score 0):

Try using;

```
$('#container').clearQueue();
$('#container').stop();
$('#container').animate(bgPos[currClick], 1500, 'swing');
```